# Parametrizing values to a snowflake query from another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to parametrize an update query reading values from a snowflake table as below.

**Snowflake query** :

```
update tgtTable set @col_name = @newVal
from srcTable
where lower(@col_name) = @old_val
```

**srcTable** :

```
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+ 
|col_name  |modified_dt |old_val     |new_val       |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+
|franchise |2021-02-05  |NDDA Boston |NCRT Colo     |
|acct_type |2021-04-13  |Chk         |Sav           |
|pref_lang |2021-05-25  |Eng-UK      |Eng-US        |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

The values of `col_name` in above table - `franchise`, `acct_type` & `pref_lang` are actual columns of the `tgtTable` which Im trying to update based on `old_val` and `new_val` of `srcTable` in the above `Snowflake query`.

But I'm running into *SQL compilation error: syntax error*

Can someone be able to help me provide a solution for this approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you running this query? Why the "@"?

Comment: I'm trying to run this query in Snowflake. I tried parametrizing col_name, old_val, and new_val from srcTable in the query but didn't work....

Comment: can you try without the `@`?

Comment: SQL executor should know what it should return before the actual execution. That's why parameters cannot replace SQL statement parts in static SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parametrize column names in SQL. Your options would be to hard code the column names and run the SQL for each column individually

```
update tgtTable T set T.franchise = S.new_val
from srcTable S
where S.col_name = 'franchise' and T.franchise = S.old_val;
```

Alternatively, you could write a stored procedure and build the SQL statement dynamically.